# Minimize $K(p||q)$, when $q$ is not normalizable?

Tags: information-theory, kullback-leibler

Let $K(p||q)$:

$$K(p||q) = \int p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \mathrm{d} x$$

where the integral goes over the common support of $p$ and $q$.

The distribution $p$ that minimizes this is $p = q$. However, if $q$ is not normalizable, is there a distribution $p$ that minimizes $K(p||q)$?

Comment: So $q$ is not a proper distribution?  Are we to assume anything about it?

Comment: If $q$ is normalizable over the support of $p$, then yes, you can just "renormalize" it. In general case, I suspect, KL is unbounded from below: for example take $q(x) = a \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p_\beta(x) = \tfrac{1}{2\beta} [|x| \le \beta]$ (square brackets evaluate to 0 or 1). Then KL is effectively minimized by maximum entropy distribution on real line with no constrains, and for our family $p_\beta$ we have $H = \log(2 \beta) = -KL$

Answer (score 3):

No.

"Not normalizable" must imply *integrable* and *non-negative* but with divergent integral.  Thus, there exists a sequence of measurable sets $ \mathcal{A}_i,\ i=1,2,3,\ldots$ for which $i \le C_i =\int_{\mathcal{A}_i} q(x)dx \lt \infty$.  Define

$$p_i(x) = \frac{1}{C_i} q(x),\ x \in \mathcal{A}_i,$$

and $p(x)= 0$ otherwise.  By construction, $p_i$ is a PDF but

$$K(p_i||q) = \frac{1}{C_i}\int_{\mathcal{A}_i} q(x) \log\left(\frac{1}{C_i}\right) dx = -\log(C_i) \lt -\log(i).$$

Since the sequence $-\log(i)$ has no lower bound, there can be no minimum value of $K(p_i||q)$, *QED*.